# React Native Navigation onPress isnt working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've tried fiddling with most React Native routing / navigation libraries, but nothing has worked so far. My attempt is to have a Login Screen as a main page, where you can press on "Register", and it would lead you to the new Register page. Is there a way to do this with individual views instead of having each one as a constant within the same file?

Example:
https://i.gyazo.com/4026fc7b8333e51f7bba2a79665b4a85.png

What I was looking to do with React Navigate was this:

**Login**

```
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
                    <Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.logo} source={require('../../../src/assets/images/image.png')} />      
                </View>
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <LoginForm />
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

**LoginForm**

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    render() {
        static navigationOptions = {
            register: 'Register',
        };
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid="transparent" style = {styles.input} 
                    autoCapitalize="none" 
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()} 
                    autoCorrect={false} 
                    keyboardType='email-address' 
                    returnKeyType="next" 
                    placeholder='Email' 
                    placeholderTextColor='rgba(225,225,225,0.7)'/>
                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid="transparent" style = {styles.input}   
                    returnKeyType="go" ref={(input)=> this.passwordInput = input} 
                    placeholder='Password' 
                    placeholderTextColor='rgba(225,225,225,0.7)' 
                    secureTextEntry/>
                <View style = {styles.spacer} />           
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text  style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity> 
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=>{this.navigate("register")}}>
                    <Text  style={styles.buttonText}>REGISTER</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>              
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isReady: false
        };
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
            Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
            Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
            Ionicons: require("native-base/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf")
        });
        this.setState({ isReady: true });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady) {
            return <Expo.AppLoading />;
        }
        return <RootNavigator/>;
    }

    const App = StackNavigator({
        Login: { screen: Login},
        Register: { screen: Register},
    });    
}
```

Although I am not sure anymore whether this is possible. I've been looking into react-native-navigation-flux although the same case happened there. Either Expo would give Error 500 and say the server isn't running, or it would say that navigate isn't existing even though declared.

Comment: how is defined the 'NAVIGATE HERE' assignement to onPress on the last TouchableOpacity declaration?

Comment: I used to have it setup so that the route.js would contain the following:

const Route = StackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Register: {screen: Register},
});

And then the onPress would call

navigate('Register')

Although it would constantly that there is no such thing as "navigate", even though supposedly it would be a prop given from the Route where I write the StackNavigator

Comment: I can edit my post to show what I did when I tried using React Navigation

Comment: the onPress prop should be a callback that gets called after the button 'REGISTER' is pressed

Comment: I've edited it now to the way I did it back when I tried. I did have the navigate function inside a anonymous callback on the onPress, although it would keep telling me that navigate doesn't exist.

Comment: I think where you call () =>{ this.navigate("register")} you should go for "Register" with upper case 'R' as you defined it in the StackNavigator

Comment: also, you can't call this.navigate cause navigate is defined as a const and not as a property. change it to onPress={()=> navigate("Register")}

Comment: Just found out the cause. I was passing the navigate prop to Login, but I was trying to acces it inside LoginForm. I passed the navigate prop into LoginForm and now it works. Sorry for the inconvenience.